# Rewrite catalog/index.php to www.domain.co.uk

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have an online shop with a welcome page. Our SEO company has asked us to get rid of the welcome page with a rewrite. I am struggling to get this to work. Can you help please?

I want to rewrite `www.domain.co.uk/catalog/index.php` to become `www.domain.co.uk` using a 301 redirect.

Comment: This is very specific to your site, and as such not a good match for our Q&A system.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks as if you've installed some software which has created the `/catalog` folder. Do you have a program which was installed there, ecommerce shopping cart maybe? Or a CMS? If so rather than messing with redirects on your index.

Move the entire folder up to the top level. Then redirect your product or regular pages from `/catalog/something` to `/something`. Use canonical attributes on your index to let Google and others know which is your primary home page. In Google and Bing Webmaster Tools areas, specify the correct domain for your index. Re-submit your sitemaps as well.

I would do this so that you can avoid having `/catalog` appear at all if possible and have `domain.co.uk/pagename.php` or `domain.co.uk/product-name`.